# What happened to the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

- Do we care about it any more?
- Is it worth continuing?
- How can we promote it to get more clicks?
- How can we prevent it becoming as
  neglected as it is currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All blogs are going away on all sites, it is a feature that SE is doing away with. They consulted Matt and Greg, as they were the mods when it was initiated. It hadn't had any updates in years, so they elected to just have it go away.

The other option was to have migrated it to a 3rd part site, which they would have assisted with, but TBH, it wasn't worth the effort as it was all very old data.